# have any SQL GROUP_CONCAT alternative function?

Tags: mysql, sql, function, group-by

here i was past my sql query.
any body know GROUP_CONCAT alternative function so let me know ?

SQL  Error :

```
<h1>A Database Error Occurred</h1>
<p>Error Number: 1140</p>
<p>In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'smartsaver.ud.id'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by</p>
```

SQL Command :

```
    SELECT ud.id, ud.url, d.document_name, d.d
                                        GROUP_CONCAT(LEFT(REPLACE(url, "document", "thumb"), CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(url, "document", "thumb")) - LOCATE(".", REVERSE(REPLACE(url, "document", "thumb")))), ".", "png")
ud.document_url
                                END as new_url, CASE WHEN ud.type = 1 THEN "Image" WHEN ud.type = 2 THEN "Video" WHEN ud.type = 3 THEN "File" WHEN ud.type = 4 THEN "Text" ELSE "" END as type, d.added_on, ud.type as document_type
    FROM tbl_uplaod_document ud
    JOIN tbl_document d ON d.id = ud.document_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_document_project_relation pr 
 ON pr.document_id = ud.document_id

    WHERE ud.is_active = 1
    AND d.is_active = 1
    AND ud.user_id = 1
    AND ud.document_id = 116
     LIMIT 10
```

Comment: you cannot use group function without group by.. try `group by id`

Comment: @danish-khan-I You can use group function without group by.

Comment: @Strawberry ofcourse but for that you need to  change `sql_mode`

Comment: @danish-khan-I. Not true. You have it back to front.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@dev5 Your code to hard to read

Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains non aggregated column 'smartsaver.ud.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by.

will be simply solved by changing the sql mode in MySQL by this command:

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
```

Thank You :-)

Comment: Thank you jayesh I was use "SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''))" command and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `select` with an aggregation function.  That makes the query an aggregation function.  But there is no `group by`.  Happily, MySQL now generally returns an error in this case.

Earlier versions of MySQL allowed a malformed query such as your using the default settings.  It would return values for the unaggregated columns from arbitrary rows.  The default settings have changed to generate an error.

You should add a `group by` for all non-aggregated columns in the `select`:

```
group by ud.id, ud.url, d.document_name, d.d, . . .
```

Your code is rather hard to read, so it is hard to pick out the unaggregated columns.